# Keeping track of number of button clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, click

Let us assume that I have a page with a CAPTCHA image.

I want to let the user try to enter the code for three times, otherwise he is not allowed to do it anymore.

How can I keep track of the number of times the "Confirm" button has been clicked.  The "Confirm" button has to perform a postback to the server every time it is clicked.

Using JavaScript is not good since if the user reloads the page, the counter would be set to zero.  How can this be done please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward. First set the counter to zero, and then update it on subsequent post backs:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack) { Session["RetryCount"] = 1; }
else
{
    int retryCount = (int)Session["RetryCount"];
    if (retryCount == 3) { // do something because it's bad }
    else { retryCount++; Session["RetryCount"] = retryCount; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)  It didn't pass my mind to do it using session.  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael :)  So this would keep track of the number of button clicks even if the user refreshes the page from the browser.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Matthew, yes because a refresh of the browser window **would be considered a post back**.

Answer (score 4):

Use [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to store the number.

Or better yet - [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The advantage of `Session` is that it is stored on the Server (AFAIK) so it can't be tampered with, and also that it will persist even when reloading the page.

Comment: +1 for ViewState, keeping in mind that if the user re-enters this page from scratch, it will be reset back to zero. And in order to keep it secure, the ViewState encryption would need to be enabled. As long as that's acceptable to the requirements, I'd choose that over Session, to avoid the overhead of having this stored on your server.