# how calculate number of clicks on a button every time modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched around on SO and I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075219/javascript-code-to-count-number-of-clicks-on-a-button?noredirect=1&lq=1) similar to what I need but didn't feet what I need.

What I have is a modal with a button on it, I want to calculate the number of clicks on that button and execute a script(scroll top) if that number is even and an other script(scroll down)  otherwise.
(since I have tried to do this scroll more simply than this way but I failed :( due to a similar button on the main page)

So this is what I have as code :

```
<script>

  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var i=0;
         $(function () { 
                    $("#modal_scroll{{ obj.id }}").click(function () {
                       i++;
                        console.log('heeeereeee',i)
                        if (i % 2 === 0) {
                            $('.modal').scrollTop(0);
                        else
                            {
                                $("#modal_scroll{{ obj.id }}").attr('href','#div_{{ obj.id }}')
                            }
                    });
                });
    })
```

The problem is that when hiding the modal the old value of `i` is not forgot. so this is the message in the console the first time modal is shown after 3 clicks on the button :

```
heeeereeee 1
heeeereeee 2
heeeereeee 3
```

and this is what is shown on console when modal is closed an reopened a second time with a 3 clicks on the button :

```
heeereee 4
heeereee 1
heeereee 5
heeereee 2
heeereee 6
heeereee 3
```

and so on ..
I don't know how to forget the old value every time modal is opened.

Any ideas  ?

Comment: Try removing your event handler `$("#modal_scroll{{ obj.id }}").click` when you're hiding modal. Right now you're adding them each time the modal is shown.

Comment: How to remove that handler ?

Comment: This should work `$("#modal_scroll{{ obj.id }}").off('click');`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Walk the old value is forgotten , but I have many modals in my page (showing details of many objects in a table) when clicking on another modal console shows `(2) heeeereeee1`  `(2) heeeereeee2)` .. 
every click shows the message twice do you have an idea how to avoid this and show only one message in the console ?

Comment: otherwise Thanks you can post it as an answer so that I can mark it :)

Comment: Do those `#modal_scroll{{ obj.id }}` have unique ids?

Comment: yes each modal has a different id

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why that is, you can try logging `$(this).attr("id");` there to be sure where the event comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your event handler when modal is hidden, otherwise you're adding new event handlers each time modal is shown. So adding `$("#modal_scroll{{ obj.id }}").off('click');` when modal is hidden should work.