# Javascript popup when two or more buttons clicked

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm in the middle of a project where I need to show a popup when two or more buttons have been clicked. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I think this could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075219/javascript-code-to-count-number-of-clicks-on-a-button

Comment: Is there any relevant code that you could add to your question?

Comment: I have written a javascript that does this, but it would be good to have some more information about the expected behaviour eg. should the pop-up appear every time a button is clicked once at least two buttons have been pressed, or should the click counter be reset each time? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the javascript below.

```js
var clicks = 0;
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicks++;
    if(clicks >= 2){
      alert('Pop-up. ' + clicks + ' clicks have been recorded.');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

Comment: And you might want to reset the `clicks` counter, once the alert is shown.

Comment: @AkshitMehra That would probably be a good idea, but it depends on what the person asking the question wants. It may be that they do not want the pop-up to appear at all after it has appeared once – the javascript can be easily edited to do any of these options, but the question is not very specific.

Comment: I agree with your point, that was just a suggestion if the OP wants that functionality, too.

Comment: I don't really know javascript at all as I just started to do things with it. However, the code you posted helped me A LOT and now my project is going forward. Thank you so much.